# Partial/Abbreviated Name Matching

Tags: mysql, fuzzy-search

Im trying to write a query that will match partial matches to stored name values.

My database looks as follows

> Blockquote

```
FirstName | Middle Name | Surname
----------------------------------
Joe       | James       | Bloggs
J         | J           | Bloggs
Joe       |             | Bloggs
Jane      |             | Bloggs
```

Now if a user enters their name as

```
J Bloggs
```

my query should return all 4 rows, as they are all potential matches.

Similarly if a user enters the name

```
J J Bloggs
```

all rows should be returned.

If a user enters their name as

```
Joe Bloggs
```

only the first three should be returned.

I have tried the following

```
SELECT * 
FROM PERSON 
WHERE CONCAT(' ',FirstName,' ',MiddleName,' ', Surname) LIKE '% Joe%'
    AND CONCAT(' ',FirstName,' ',MiddleName,' ', Surname, ' ') LIKE '% Bloggs%';
```

But this doesn't return 'J J Bloggs'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would `J J Bloggs` match all _four_ records?  Shouldn't it not match the final two records, which have no middle name?

Comment: I'm not sure with your logic : if user enters `Joe Bloggs` you want to return `Joe James Bloggs` AND `J J Bloggs` AND `Joe Bloggs` but not `Jane Bloggs`? Why return `J J Bloggs` and not `Jane Bloggs`? And about `J J Bloggs`, same remark as Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: @MickaelLeger For the first example, I think it should match because in this case no middle name was input, so we don't check it.  For the second part, `Jane` and `Joe` are mutually different first names, so they don't match, whereas `J` and `Joe` match via one being a substring/abbreviation of the other.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sometimes people omit their middle names and other times the enter them, I want to ensure they cant work around the system using that flaw.

Comment: @MickaelLeger I would return J J Bloggs as it doesn't show any obvious non-matching characteristics. 'J J Bloggs' vs 'Joe Bloggs' could easily be a match. Whereas Jane != Joe

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's what I thought, so if I understand : if user enters `Jo J Bloggs` something like `Joe Bloggs` or `Jonathan Bloggs` must be return but not `Jane Bloggs`?

Comment: Yeah...that's my take on it.  Except, not sure why the OP expects all rows to match `J J Bloggs` when actually two records have _no_ middle name.

Comment: He said it's because some people forget middle name...so if user enters middle name : it should return row that match what user enters OR row with no middle name, but if middle name is different nothing? Eg. users enter s `J J Bloggs` -> return : `Joe Bloggs`, `Joe John Bloggs` but not `Joe Peter Bloggs`?

Comment: Seriously...can't they come up with better dummy names on this site, maybe dead US Presidents, or possibly NBA players?

Comment: @MickaelLeger Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your logic correctly, any of the three input name components is considered to be a match if it either is a substring of a value in the table, or vice-versa.  That is, `J` matches `Joe`, but also `Joe` matches to `J`.  Using this logic, we can write the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    (INSTR(FirstName, 'J') > 0 OR INSTR('J', FirstName) > 0) AND
    (INSTR(MiddleName, 'J') > 0 OR INSTR('J', MiddleName) > 0 OR MiddleName IS NULL) AND
    (INSTR(Surname, 'Bloggs') > 0 OR INSTR('Bloggs', Surname) > 0);
```

### Demo

Note that the middle name has some additional logic.  If the middle name be missing in a record (i.e. it is `NULL`), then we wave the requirement for the middle names to match.

Comment: I didn't knew `INSTR` function, can be usefull for for this kind of task ! But is it faster than `LIKE %X%` ? I might be wrong but `where INSTR(firstname, "j") > 0` and `where firstname like '%j%'` did the same no? It will return a result if `j` is somewhere in `firstname`?

Comment: Ok I like this. As much as I said I wanted to check the name as a whole string this seems like a good approach. We have additional identity verification services running that will likely fail if the user jumbles up their name, denying them service anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need `OR` instead of `AND`...

```
SELECT * 
FROM PERSON 
WHERE CONCAT(' ',FirstName,' ',MiddleName,' ', Surname) LIKE '% Joe%'
    OR CONCAT(' ',FirstName,' ',MiddleName,' ', Surname, ' ') LIKE '% Bloggs%';
```

Comment: *facepalm* Seems to do the job! Thanks

Comment: @mwild great, glad to help

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What sort of edge cases? Do you have any examples? Effectively I am trying to mitigate the chances of users signing up multiple times.

Comment: For starters, this doesn't check the individual components of the name against each record, it just does a blanket concatenation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Is that not a benefit? If I didn't do that getting around the system would be as easy as putting my first middle name on the end of the first name?